# XPath 2.0 implementations?

Tags: c, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

Are there any XML libraries that support XPath 2.0?

I'm specifically looking for an open-source, portable, C-compatible implementation, but for the sake of this question, I'd also like to know about any others. So far, I've only heard of the Java/.NET library [SAXON](http://saxon.sourceforge.net).

**EDIT**: Libraries that only support XPath 1.0 (according to their websites):

- [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/)
- [Xalan](https://xalan.apache.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath 2.0 is a subset of XQuery 1.0 so for example http://www.zorba.io/home or http://xqilla.sourceforge.net/HomePage should do.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [one](http://benibela.de/sources_en.html#internettools) for Pascal. It also supports XQuery and JSONiq.

Answer (score 1):

Michael Kay is working on an c/c++ version of xslt 2.0 / xpath 2.0.

http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml
https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon-c